# Can we use bootstrap modal without javascript

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Can we use bootstraps modal to delete data from a database or other source without writing any javascript code? In the getbootstrap page it says we can choose either using modal with data attributes or javascript. But I can't find any example how to delete stuff without using javascipt.

Answer (score 2):

Data-attributes also require Bootstrap's Javascript to function. Firstly to make the modal functional you need the javascript, although you don't need to write any of it.

Deleting data from a database requires server-side scripting. So typically you will need PHP and SQL for that. Either you can use Javascript to send command to an external PHP script, or directly include the required PHP into the page. You will certainly have to use some scripting.

Comment: I'm programming with Asp.Net MVC, so I made the server-side method for the delete. I know that bootstrap uses javascript. I want to know if I cant avoid writing javascript code and only use data attributes.